# Why does Vue.js not work in Shopify theme?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, shopify

I want to use Vue.js in my shopify theme. so added this code in theme.
But it's not working. showing no results now! I'm not sure what is the issue. Could someone help me to fix this simple issue? Thank you

note: I have been created a `test.html` and copy pasted below code. but It was working correctly on simple `html` file. but why it's not working on shopify?

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
</div>

<script>
  console.log('run-vue');
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: What file in your theme did you add this code to? Have you confirmed that any of this code is loading on the page? If so, does your `console.log` appear and are you getting any errors?

Comment: For test, I added above code into theme.liquid just after<body> tag.  As you can see, there is console.log. it's display successfuly without any issues. Seems can't use vue.js in shopify without webpack?

Comment:   Is `{{ message }}` supposed to be a Liquid template variable or a Vue template variable? If the latter, what happens if you wrap your app div with `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}` tags to prevent Shopify from trying to parse that template command server-side before sending it to the client?

Comment: And you can definitely use Vue or any other arbitrary framework on a Shopify store - All Shopify does is provide you with a templating language that you can use to access store-related information. You can load any arbitrary JS (and I have seen a _lot_ of arbitrary javascript loaded into various stores!) The trick though is that lots of templating languages use similar delimiters, so if you use something that also uses `{{}}` or `{%%}` syntax you need to tell Shopify not to parse those sections server-side.

Comment: @DaveB Thanks FYI. I think it's a correct answer!

Comment: Huzzah! Glad we could troubleshoot this - I have taken that comment and turned it into an answer for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TLDR: Vue is using template syntax that is too similar to Liquid - you need to use `{% raw %}` tags.

You can definitely use Vue or any other arbitrary framework on a Shopify store - All Shopify does is provide you with a templating language that you can use to access store-related information. You can load any arbitrary JS (and I have seen a lot of arbitrary javascript loaded into various stores!) The trick though is that lots of templating languages use similar delimiters, so if you use something that also uses `{{}}` or `{%%}` syntax you need to tell Shopify not to parse those sections server-side.

In your case, the mounting point would just need to be updated to:

```
{% raw %}
  <div id="app">
    {{ message }}
  </div>
{% endraw %}
```

Comment: But if we use `raw` tags, we can't reach shopify vars anymore. For example asset_url.

Comment: @YasinYörük - Correct, and a big reason why I don't like mixing random frameworks with templating languages. There are a few ways that you could work around this though: If you have access to the asset name in Liquid you can use `endraw` to close the unparsed section, drop in your asset, then open a new `raw` section immediately afterwards. If that doesn't work, you can create a global object in `theme.liquid` where you drop a test file name with the `asset_url` filter and use that to get a filepath string that you can use to build asset urls for arbitrary files.

Answer (score 1):

In Vue 3 you can use custom delimiters:

```
Vue.createApp({ delimiters: ["${", "}"] })
```

Then in the template:

```
<div>${this.someVueData}</div>
```